# Property mapping has wrong number of columns

Tags: hibernate, embeddable

I am using hibernate 4.2.21 version. I have partial entities and I used @Embedded and @Embeddable annotations. When trying to run project , it gives an exception;

> property mapping has wrong number of columns: com.demo.School.teacher type: object

School entity class

```
@Entity(name = "School")
public class{
   public String schoolId;
   public String schoolName;

   @Embedded
   @AttributeOverrides({
      @AttributeOverride(name = "teacherName",column = @Column(name = "teacherName")),
      @AttributeOverride(name = "teacherPhone",column = @Column(name = "teacherPhone")),
   })
   @XmlElements({
      @XmlElement(name = "TeacherU", type = TeacherU.class),
      @XmlElement(name = "TeacherH", type = TeacherH.class)
   })
   public object teacher;

   //getters and setters 
}
```

Teacher (University) entity class

```
@Embeddable
public class TeacherU {
   public String teacherName;
   public String teacherPhone;

   //getters and setters 
}
```

Teacher (High School) entity class

```
@Embeddable
public class TeacherH {
   public String teacherName;
   public String teacherPhone;

   //getters and setters 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Teacher shouldn't be declared as an Object, change

```
public object teacher;
```

to

```
public Teacher teacher;
```

Comment: I edited the question because it has two different types of Teacher entities that I didn't mention, sorry.

Comment: Teacher must be declared as concrete class in School. Use discriminator column if you want to have two different teachers in one table.

Comment: Is there another solution ? Because, these are generated classes from .xsd files with wsimport tool and I can't change class signature.